# Azure.Data.Tables QueryAsync filtering erring with multiple filter conditions

Tags: c#, azure, azure-table-storage, azure-tablequery

In the old SDK Azure Table you could create FilterConditions like the following

```
var partitionFilter = TableQuery.GenerateFilterCondition("PartitionKey", QueryComparisons.Equal, symbolRoot);
    var startDateFilter =
        TableQuery.GenerateFilterConditionForDate("TradeDate", QueryComparisons.GreaterThanOrEqual, startDate);
    var endDateFilter =
        TableQuery.GenerateFilterConditionForDate("TradeDate", QueryComparisons.LessThanOrEqual, endDate);

    var filter = TableQuery.CombineFilters(
        TableQuery.CombineFilters(
            partitionFilter,
            TableOperators.And,
            startDateFilter),
        TableOperators.And, endDateFilter);
```

I'd love to be able to continue with that pattern but....

In the new Azure.Data.Tables SDK a lot has changed
I see no methods to create filters with multiple parameters, even though the QueryAsync methods accepts a filter as a parameter.
The reference material for it, found [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/main/sdk/tables/Azure.Data.Tables/samples/Sample4QueryEntities.md)
shows how to create a single parameter filter, but not a multiple parameter filter.

This method below fails because the DateTime conversion apparently is not supported within the filtering

```
public async Task<List<EquityDataEntity>> GetEquityPriceDataXDaysBackAsync(string symbol, int daysBackFromToday)
{
    if (daysBackFromToday > 0)
    {
        daysBackFromToday *= -1; // put it proper form for Add... method
    }
    var data = await TableClient!
        .QueryAsync<EquityDataEntity>(u => u.PartitionKey == symbol.ToUpper()
                                  && Convert.ToDateTime(u.RowKey) >= DateTime.Now.AddDays(daysBackFromToday))  
        //Yes, unfortunately the RowKey is the date
        .ToListAsync();

    return data;
}
```

> "Method ToDateTime not supported."

My two questions are:

1. Is there a way to generate filters outside the method to use within the method as was done in prior SDK?
2. How can I accomplish the date comparison in the Query method if the above is not doable and which requires a filter with multiple parameters (PartitionKey and date comparison)?

**Update:**

To note, the table structure is as follows
The PartitionKey is a symbol like GLD, TSLA etc
The RowKey is a Date like 2023-03-03

I have tried generating the filter like so

```
var filter = TableClient.CreateQueryFilter($"PartitionKey eq {symbol.ToUpper()} and RowKey gt {dateDataStarts}");
```

which produces this

> PartitionKey eq 'GLD' and RowKey gt datetime'2021-10-20T17:42:01.3095704Z'

which according to the docs is what the OData filter should look like
but it fails.

doing it with LINQ like so

```
var data = await TableClient!
        .QueryAsync<EquityDataEntity>(u => u.PartitionKey == symbol.ToUpper() && u.RowKey >= DateTime.Now.AddDays(daysBackFromToday).ToString())
        .ToListAsync();
    return data;
```

creates a VS2022 error

> Operator 'operator' cannot be applied to operands of type 'string' and 'string'

replacing >= with gt doesn't work either

**Update 2**

The filter works now. The issue was the date was in the wrong format.
This code now works as expected.

```
 var dateDataStarts = DateTime.Now.AddDays(daysBackFromToday).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
   
 var filter = TableClient.CreateQueryFilter($"PartitionKey eq {symbol.ToUpper()} and RowKey gt {dateDataStarts}");
```

which generates the OData filter as "PartitionKey eq 'GLD' and RowKey gt '2021-10-20'"

Comment: `RowKey` is of `String` data type (just like `PartitionKey`). What you would have to do is convert `DateTime.Now.AddDays(daysBackFromToday)` to string and do the comparison.

Comment: I tried that but get the error that you cannot compare strings using gt or lt

Comment: Okay, I know why that’s failing, I have to us the gt and lt and not the > or <. I’ll try that again

Comment: In LINQ, I think you should be able to do so. You are anyway doing `==` for PartitionKey comparison.

Comment: Guarav, please see my Update section at the end of the original post.

Comment: Added an answer. HTH.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the 1st one where you are specifying OData filter, you would need to convert your `dateDataStarts` variable to string. So your code would be something like:

```
var filter =
    TableClient.CreateQueryFilter($"PartitionKey eq {symbol.ToUpper()} and RowKey gt {dateDataStarts.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")}");
```

For the 2nd one where you are using LINQ, you are correct. You cannot use `>=` for string comparison. You will need to use [`String.CompareTo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.compareto?view=net-7.0). So your code would be something like:

```
TableClient.QueryAsync<TableEntity>(u => u.PartitionKey == symbol && u.RowKey.CompareTo(dateDataStarts.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")) >= 0)
```

Comment: If you read my update, I did figure it out from your comments. Thank you

Comment: Awesome! Sorry, I did not notice that you already figured that out.

Comment: One last question, how would I convert this LINQ; u => u.TradeDate >= startDate && u.TradeDate <= endDate to an OData filter when TradeDate is just a property in the table and is in this format  2021-03-18T04:00:00Z. I have it working the LINQ way but im using OData filters everywhere else and Id like to keep it that way

Comment: You would need to prefix your date/time values with `datetime`. Your OData filter query will be something like `TradeDate ge datetime'2021-03-18T04:00:00Z' and TradeDate le date time'2021-03-21T04:00:00Z'`. HTH.